# remember a data set to avoid redundancy

Tags: mysql, caching, memcached, laravel-5

a user will be answering random questions (pulled from DB) and once he answers a question, he shall no longer be asked to answer it again.

So I need a way to remember the questions answered by the application users.

I was thinking about storing the answered questions in a separated table along with the user_id, but given the nature of the app (quick "yes" "no" questions), every user might end up answering thousands of questions. I'm not sure updating and accessing such a large table in a regular basis is a good solution.

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Thousands of answers from one user?  Really?

If that's a real possibility, you can store the set of answered questions as a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which can be serialized to a fixed size; see [PyBloom](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybloom/1.1) for one implementation, that can easily be adopted to store the filter state in a 
BLOB or VARBINARY column.

If the users will answer several questions in one session, you'll probably want to keep a copy of the current status in memory, as well as persisting it when it changes.

Aren't you going to keep track of the answers? Why can't you just query the existing answers for a user to select an unanswered question?  If I were doing this, I'd try the simplest solution first, and only go for the fancy solution when (and if) the simple solution ran out of gas.